# program in C is crashing when more memory is used

Tags: c, memory

I have to do as a school assigment small program in C that will read standart input and prints some standart output. To be more specific, it's about reading numbers and sorting them.

(you can skip this, it's just for understanding the code)
First line of the input should determine how many lines of numbers there will be. Second line is ammount of numbers in next line. Third line are to concrete numbers. Fourth line is ammount of numbers in next line and so on until it reaches K number of lines. Restrictions are 0 < K <= 10 (max 10 sequences), each sequence can contain max 10.000.000 numbers and each number's value is max 10.000.000

**Example** 
Input:

1. 2 *//which means that there will be 2 sequences (lines) of numbers and their corresponding ammount*
2. 3 *//in the first sequence there will be 3 numbers*
3. 5 99912 45 //first sequence
4. 6 *//in the second sequence there will be 6 numbers*
5. 9489498 22131 0 521313 7988956 5 //second sequence

Ouptup:

0 5 5 45 22131 99912 521313 7988956 9489498

So I have done a working program but it seems to be unstable with higher values. However I can't determine when and where exactly the program fails. On my computer, I have tested all possible max values and it returned correct output in reasonable time, but on a school server where tests are done it just can't handle high values and fails.

There is one thing, that the program should only use C, not C++, but I am not very sure of differences between them and as I was using C++ compiler, it's possible that my code isn't just raw C.

I am a C beginner and this is something like "Hello world" for me, so please, can you just quick look through the code and say what can cause the unstability? Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {    
    int k, n, i, y, x, index = 0;
    int *numbers = (int*) malloc(100000000 * sizeof(int));
    if(numbers == NULL){
        exit(1);
    }
    scanf("%d", &k);
    for (x = 0; x < k; x++) {
        y = 0;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        while(scanf("%d", &i) > 0){
            numbers[index++] = i;
            if(++y == n){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for(y = 0;y < index;y++){   //find and print all 0's, because later I will use 0 as a
                                //already used (printed) element in array and ignore it      
        if(numbers[y] == 0){
            if(y == index-1){
                printf("0");
            }else{
                printf("0 ");
            }
        }
    }
    int smallest, smallestIndex;
    for(x = 0;x < index;x++){   //print all other numbers in ascending order
        smallest = 0;
        for(y = 0;y < index;y++){  //find current smallest number
            if((numbers[y] < smallest || smallest == 0) && numbers[y] != 0){
                smallest = numbers[y];
                smallestIndex = y;
            }
        }
        numbers[smallestIndex] = 0;
        if(smallest > 0){
            if(x == index-1){
                printf("%d", smallest);
            }else{
                printf("%d ", smallest);
            }
        }
    }
    free(numbers);
    numbers = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After a quick glance, it looks like you are using just C other than perhaps the `//` comments. Current versions of C might support this now, I'm not sure.

Comment: Also, can you give us more details about what fails on your school server? Do you get an error message? If so, please copy and paste it here so we can help you figure out a solution.

Comment: You don't need to pre-allocate that much memory. Search for the `realloc` function.

Comment: I can't get any more information of why it crashes, the server's test tool just returns what values were tested and if the test with those values was succesfull.

I will try that realloc function

Comment: Maybe what crashes is the test tool.

Comment: Test your program at the limits.

Comment: Do I detect a hint of sarcasm?

Comment: Are you really allocating a 381 megabyte block? You don't need that much!

Comment: @jsn I guess you really do need exactly that much (in the worst case): *each sequence can contain max 10.000.000 numbers and each number's value is max 10.000.000*

Comment: I think the error is some kind of timeout.  This program will run for a very long time on a maximal input of 100.000.000 numbers -- days at least, if not years...

Comment: I forget to mention that it crashes when inputs are like this - K (number of sequences) is 10 and each of the 10 sequence contains just 200 numbers so inputs are far away from max possible values. When inputs are K = 5 and ammount of numbers in each sequence is 100, it passess and return correct output. But despite of inputs I am always allocating 100000000 * sizeof(int) of memory, so maybe that's the problem, but I don't see any reason why, memory usage is always same. BTW, is it possible that it is caused by other versions of compilers?

Comment: @user10099 did you try using `realloc` yet?

Comment: Might not be the issue, but if all inputs are 0, your smallestIndex value will be uninitialized. numbers[smallestIndex] = 0; That could be accessing memory before  or after the numbers array.

Comment: @KeithMiller I saw your code (thanks) I did something like this -> http://codeviewer.org/view/code:2a47 . I keep track of the current allocated memory and raise it everytime before new sequence is appended to the array. I think I don't need to use malloc(), because when NULL pointer is given to the realloc(), it just behave like malloc(). Anyway it seems to be working on my PC, but I can't test it on school's server till tomorrow so we will see then

Comment: Okay good luck buddy. I hope it works for you.

Comment: @DavidMFrey thanks, so I'll just assign value 0 right in a declaration and it should be ok

Comment: @KeithMiller thanks, I hope that too :) But I still don't get it because it doesn't seem like memory problem to me. With my first version of code I allocated constant maximum memory all the time and it could handle low values, but not high values. Why? Memory usage was always the same.

Comment: So I tested it with realloc(), but result was same - it failed with higher values. Then I was googling a little and found function qsort() which is in stdlib library. I rewrote the code and used qsort() instead of my sorting algorithm and it WORKED with any value :) So probably there was something wrong with my sorting code .. anyway thank you all, here is the final working version of my code http://codeviewer.org/view/code:2a4c

Comment: You should have posted the exact input that lead to failure.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you give, I think this is simply a resource limitation on the server. The server simply runs out of memory and your `malloc()` fails. I suggest you debug or do this:

```
if(numbers == NULL){
    printf("malloc() failed\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Well the malloc function works all right and it always returns pointer to that array, I don't think that there are any limitations. As I said, this is input related problem and with small input values it works correctly, so it fails somewhere after the allocation

Comment: You are mistaken. The problem is that he isn't allocating enough memory.

Answer (score 0):

The code for printing the initial zeros is suspicious:

```
for(y = 0;y < index;y++){   //find and print all 0's, because later I will use 0 as a
                            //already used (printed) element in array and ignore it      
    if(numbers[y] == 0){
        if(y == index-1){
            printf("0");
        }else{
            printf("0 ");
        }
    }
```

Suppose you have a sequence with 0 as the last element (e.g. 1 2 3 4 5 0); i guess this code will print just `0` with no space after it, and the subsequent code will print `1 2 3 4 5`, so you will get something like `01 2 3 4 5`.

I understand that you want the output to be as beautiful as possible, that is, without a space at the end. Please also note that a newline (`\n`) at the end of output might be good.

Comment: Thanks, you're right and I was thinking about it but was too lazy to fix it. I guess I'll just print "0 " all the time because in every sequence there should be at least one not null number.

Answer (score -1):

I rewrote beginning parts of your program to get you on the right path. This should help you but I can't be sure since I don't really know what is causing your program to crash.

This implements the `realloc` function which should make your program drastically more efficient than it is now. If you don't know what `realloc` is you can read about it [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc), and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BUFFER 256                                                  //for memory management         

int main(void) 
{    
    int k, n, i, y , x, index = 0, bff;                             //declare integer 'bff' and set it to BUFFER
    int *numbers = NULL, *tmp;                                      //declare a pointer (numbers) for allocated memory, and a pointer (tmp) for the realloc function

    if(!(numbers = malloc(BUFFER * sizeof(int))))                   //allocate space for 'bff' integers
    {
        exit(1);                                                    //allocation failed
    }
    scanf("%d", &k);
    for (x = 0; x < k; x++) 
    {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        while(scanf("%d", &i) > 0)
        {
            if(bff <= index)                                        //if the size of index grows larger than the amount of space we allocated
            {
                bff += BUFFER;                                      //increase the size of bff by BUFFER
                if(!(tmp = realloc(numbers, bff * sizeof(int))))    //resize our allocated memory block using the tmp pointer 
                {
                    free(numbers);                                      //allocation failed so free already allocated memory
                    exit(1);                                        //and terminate the program
                }
                numbers = tmp;                                      //make numbers point to the same location as tmp
                numbers[index++] = i;                               
                if(++y == n) break;
            }
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
    free(numbers);
    return 0;
}
```

Keep in mind there are more efficient ways to use realloc. I just posted this here to get you on the right track. Good luck!

Comment: Why increment in chunks of 256? Each sequence starts with the number of elements in that sequence. Wouldn't it be better to use that number for `realloc`? That way only `k` allocs will be needed.

Comment: I just posted this so that OP could get a feel for the `realloc` function. It is their choice on how they want to implement it. But I personally prefer increasing the size of allocated space by fixed amounts each time.

Answer (score -1):

You are allocating the wrong amount of memory. The specification states that **each** sequence can contain 10 million values whereas you allocate a fixed amount. There may be up to **k*10 million** values of input, and you cannot know that the amount you allocate is enough.

As pointed out by m0skit0, the problem may also be due to over-allocation.

To fix the problem you should allocate the needed amount of memory, no more, no less.
Use the sequence length provided for each sequence to do that.
Also, you need to check the return value of `malloc` and `realloc`. If the return value is `NULL` then the allocation failed and you should print an error message and `exit`.

Comment: It allocates 100000000 (100 million) values, not 10 million (look at the code)

Comment: My mistake. The essence of my answer is still correct - he **is** allocating the wrong amount of memory.